# Notations in the statistical analysis of experimental research

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, f-test

I am very new to experimental setup and have recently started to learn about designing experiments and analyzing the results. In the papers that I read there are notations that I am unfamiliar with. I am particularly talking about `t()`, `p`, `ds`, `dz`, `F(,)`, and `ƞ`notations. In the following I provide some examples of how these notation been used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I highly appreciate if someone can give me some hints on what each notation means or direct me to some resources that I learn from.

Comment: Can you give a citation for the quote?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen  
Silva, R. R., Garcia-Marques, T., & Reber, R. (2017). The informative value of type of repetition: Perceptual and conceptual fluency influences on judgments of truth. Consciousness and Cognition, 51, 53-67.

Comment: Please add new info as an edit to the post. Comments are easily overseen, and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

- $t$ is a statistic from a [Student *t*-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)
- $F$ is a statistic from an [*F*-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) used in  analysis of variance
- $p$ is a [*p*-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) suggesting how likely it is that the result observed or a result as or more extreme occurs under the null hypothesis
- $d$ is probably [Cohen's *d*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d), an estimate of effect size
- $\eta^2$ is probably another statistic [eta-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Eta-squared_(%CE%B72)) related to effect size, estimating a ratio of variance explained